# Security vulnerability testing tool for .NET web applications?

Tags: .net, security, web-applications, penetration-testing

I am planning to check my website against all common security vulnerabilities like cross site scripting ,sql injection etc. Can somebody tell me is there any automated tool which I can run for my .net web app and find all security flaws exist. I tried CAt.net but it is not able to support big apps. i saw abt owsap but againt it is also not automated one. I am looking for something which can tell me file name and method name etc.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few free tools for automated vulnerability discovery.

Skipfish - open source automated web application scanner
http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/
Actively developed and maintained

GrendelScan - open source automated web application scanner
http://grendel-scan.com/

Netsparker Community Edition
http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/
Free, limited version of Netsparker

RatProxy
Non-intercepting proxy that performs vuln discovery
http://code.google.com/p/ratproxy/

Here are a few to get you started.

The best approach is to perform manual testing and use automated testing to cover 'low-hanging fruit' scenarios.

Comment: thnks any idea how qualys is, i heard they r really good in this segment

Answer (score 2):

Give [Skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) a try. It takes a little bit extra effort to install it on windows (you have to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)), but it's a pretty solid tool.

Answer (score 1):

[CAT.NET](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/02/22/Using-CATNET-Code-Analysis-Tool.aspx) is helpful, but only when run as a command line for large applications. Using the visual studio plugin, I cant get it to run for crap on larger projects either.

Comment: yeah this is the issue with CAT.NET as it cannot go beyond 1200 MB. but sometimes it even fails for smaller projects specially for web site projects. It was faling for my webiste, to overcome this i installed web deployemnt project given by MS and created a single DLL for my website(normally website creates dynamic dlls) then I ran this tool against this DLL and got success. While running this tool pls make sure you close other IDE if it is opened.